# ios continuous webservice call

Tags: ios, web-services, mapkit

iam developing an app where there are two users (observer and driver). observer will track driver position in map, so i need to send lat,long of driver to server continuously, so how can i call a server continuously so driver position get updated on observer map view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are other options out there, but you can always use a NSTimer to fire a trigger.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html